# How to increase RAM on Jungle testnet?

Tags: ram, testnet

My contract requires 350KB of RAM on the blockchain but it seems that [jungle testnet](http://jungle.cryptolions.io/#home) only provides around 200KB of RAM size.
Can the RAM on testnet be increased somehow?

The error I am getting while setting the contract is:

```
account <my-account-name> has insufficient ram; needs 339413 bytes has 207693 bytes
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the **buyram** action of **system** contract.
The above transaction can be performed using cleos as shown below.

```
cleos --url <jungle-testnet-url> system buyram <payer-account> <receiver-account> --kbytes 1000
```

Comment: Nice explanation ....

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is perfect.

Anyway, to buy RAM for myself, in my local node on the Jungle Testnet, I use the following code:

```
./cleos.sh system buyram <myaccountname> <myaccountname> --kbytes 200
```

Answer (score 0):

we can also add the required amount of RAM through scatter Desktop:
if you configured the network setting and add your account correctly. you will get this kind of UI where you can pretty easily manage the amount of your RAM,CPU,NET bandwidth.
Please make sure you have some EOS in your account.For jungle test net you can add freely by adding Faucet.

[image]

Click on manage and you will get this .Like this:

[image]

Sorry, due to lack of time I can't edit the images.