# What is the RAM price on Jungle testnet

Tags: ram, price

I want to buy 250KB of RAM on Jungle testnet but don't know the price.

in [this](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2033/how-to-increase-ram-on-jungle-testnet) thread the answer suggests the command
`cleos --url <jungle-testnet-url> system buyram <payer-account> <receiver-account> --kbytes 1000`

but now the command does not have --kbytes option, here is the [doc ref](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-system-buyram)

Can anyone help to find that info?
THanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It currently cost `0.9298 EOS` to purchase 1024 bytes of RAM on the Jungle Testnet.

`0.9298 * 250 = 232.45 EOS` estimated to purchase 250 kbytes of RAM.

The documentation you linked to is not current. Please refer to [the v1.7.4 eosio repo](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/v1.7.4/programs/cleos/main.cpp#L1502).

```
   buyram_subcommand(CLI::App* actionRoot) {
      auto buyram = actionRoot->add_subcommand("buyram", localized("Buy RAM"));
      buyram->add_option("payer", from_str, localized("The account paying for RAM"))->required();
      buyram->add_option("receiver", receiver_str, localized("The account receiving bought RAM"))->required();
      buyram->add_option("amount", amount, localized("The amount of tokens to pay for RAM, or number of bytes/kibibytes of RAM if --bytes/--kbytes is set"))->required();
      buyram->add_flag("--kbytes,-k", kbytes, localized("buyram in number of kibibytes (KiB)"));
      buyram->add_flag("--bytes,-b", bytes, localized("buyram in number of bytes"));
      add_standard_transaction_options(buyram, "payer@active");
      buyram->set_callback([this] {
         EOSC_ASSERT( !kbytes || !bytes, "ERROR: --kbytes and --bytes cannot be set at the same time" );
         if (kbytes || bytes) {
            send_actions( { create_buyrambytes(from_str, receiver_str, fc::to_uint64(amount) * ((kbytes) ? 1024ull : 1ull)) } );
         } else {
            send_actions( { create_buyram(from_str, receiver_str, to_asset(amount)) } );
         }
      });
   }
```

The `amount` parameter can either be an amount in EOS to spend, or `--bytes` or `--kbytes`

> "The amount of tokens to pay for RAM, or number of bytes/kibibytes of RAM if --bytes/--kbytes is set"

Comment: I have tried without amount and with --kbytes and received an error, but that was because of insufficient balance. Now it works, thank you.